Identifying: Unknown plant in pot with broad leaves
A plant with broad leaves and buds has grown in my pot. However, I couldn't determine its type.






Where about are you?

I am from turkey. ı will add another pictures. This is what it looks like in another pot. Their soils are different. That's why their development is different. And this pot has produced a bud. And I searched on yandex image searcher. It could be "teasel" ?

Looks like only a couple of days from flowering and the post is 3 days old. Any update? Nice tomatoes!
